# Periods and Colons

Tags: writing-style

Which is the proper way to list information:

SKE No. 1450 OR SKE No.: 1450

I am using this in the subject of Reports that look like this:

RE:  Jones v. Smith
     April 14, 2015
     SKE No. 1450
     Claim No. EB27

It looks cleaner to me without the colon, but my partners insist on using the colon, as I believe attorneys we work with format it this way.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There isn't a single way to format such references; what is "proper" is dictated by the prevailing authority, whether that is a legal jurisdiction, your organization's style manual, or your editor. For instance, the most common legal citation system in use in the U.S. is the [Bluebook](https://www.legalbluebook.com/), but that wouldn't be relevant if you were writing a piece for a publication that uses AP Style or Chicago Style. You haven't given us enough information to offer any other advice.

Comment: If you want absolute readability, then I'd suggest that the colon implies a label, which doesn't work properly in a line of text. Indeed, even the *No.* is probably unnecessary: *RE: Jones v. Smith; April 14, 2015; SKE 1450; Claim EB278*